# if radio button is checked - return function

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

if radio button 'yes' is checked i need to return a date picker function. how do i do this

radio buttons

```
<br><label for="return_journey">would you like a return journey?</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="return" value="yes">Yes
<br>
<input type="radio" name="return" value="no">No
</form><br><br>
```

date picker

```
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change",function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change",function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach the change event to your inputs and figure out which one has been selected. You can do it like that:

```
$('input[name=return]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "yes" && $(this).is(":checked")) {
        // CODE GOES HERE
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cfakmxm9/

Comment: //CODE GOES HERE- do you me the date picker function?

Comment: @st3ph2010 Yes. All you need to do is to add your DatePicker code here, nothing more.

Comment: thank guys. although i have put all the code together and it does not work. i have put an alert in just to see what is working. the date picker will not appear but the exact code it put in. can someone tell me where im going wrong?

Comment: @st3ph2010 Did you do this inside a `$(document).ready(function() { /** HERE */ })`?